# Svn update paths from a file in command line. How? Is it possibly?

Tags: svn

I have a lot of file paths in a file which should be updated. But I do not know, how I can do this. I tried to use `<` `operator`, but it is not working. If I update one by one, it takes long time.

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you update the whole project directory at once?

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary files (.pdf, .doc, .arxml etc.) which are not required for compiling. The whole repo is more than 3,5 GB. Only the source code is about 150 MB.

I have written a script for this, but now I update 30 files at the same time. This not a good way, because if the path depth is too deep, it can be run out of the space in cmd. That will be the best if I can use file.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in such a case is to use SVN's `changelist` mechanism.

You can create your own list first:

```
$> svn changelist MYLIST /src/cpp/foo
$> svn changelist MYLIST /src/cpp/bar
```

And then you can use it during your update like this:

```
$> svn update --changelist MYLIST
```

This way, only the file in the list `MYLIST` will be updated.

Note that you can also use changelists to commit certain files only.